# Reset View in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, reset

For some reason, the layout and sizes of various panels in my copy of Visual Studio 2008 has gone all wonky -- for example, the `Error` and `Output` windows appear in the same tab group as my code, and their position doesn't persist if I attempt to manually move them where I want them to go. Is there some sort of way to reset all panels to their default state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this will reset your settings to their factory state:

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

In the future, you might want to consider exporting your settings (after you get them where you want them) using the **"Tools/Import and Export Settings ..." wizard** in Visual Studio.

If you reset in the future, you can then either use the wizard, or use the command

```
devenv /resetsettings {SettingsFile}
```

Where {SettingsFile} is your previously exported settings

Comment: This worked, and good advice on the Import/Export settings -- thanks!

Comment: No problem.  I also store my exported settings under my 'Dropbox' location -- so those settings are easily accessed either from my dev box at home, or my work machine.  More info on DropBox (a free service) here: http://www.getdropbox.com/

Comment: Alternatively you can use Live Sync (http://sync.live.com) to sync the settings file across multiple machines without the need to upload it to external server.

Comment: You can do all of the above from Tools>Import and export settings - there's no need to resort to the command line.

Comment: "Visual Studio Package Loading failed". Helped me to solve using this.